# Orika class com.sun.proxy is not accessible

Tags: java, scala, java-8, orika

I´m using Orika to map from a `Akka typed actor proxy instance` to `DTO` and then from that `DTO instance` to the `proxy instance` in the way back.

The map from the `Akka typed actor proxy instance` to a `DTO` class is fine, but when I get the dto instance and I want to transform back to the Akka typed actor proxy instance Orika throw an exception

Here my code:

```
    TestDaoDTO dto = mapper.map(aggregateRoot, TestDaoDTO.class);
    TestAggregateRoot other = mapper.map(dto, aggregateRoot); --> this mapper fail
```

AggreagateRoot is a `class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy178`

And the exception says

```
ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.CompilerStrategy$SourceCodeGenerationException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy178 is not accessible
```

Answer (score 1):

You should unwrap the proxy to the "real" class. This code can be used for this purpose:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> T unwrap(T object) throws Exception {
    if (AopUtils.isAopProxy(object) && object instanceof Advised) {
        return (T) ((Advised) object).getTargetSource().getTarget();
    } else {
        return object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is not passing this condition (AopUtils.isAopProxy(object) && object instanceof Advised) I´m going to edit my question because this proxy class is a Akka typed actor, my fault when I mention to Spring

Comment: @paul you probably need to find something similar for Akka then. Googling for it didn't turn up anything useful for me, but you may try investigating the proxy object with reflection - what interfaces does it implement? Perhaps there will be an Akka interface similar to `Advised` that will let you access the wrapped object.

Comment: Np worries it was because I nneded a custom mapper of Orika